# Using UIControlEventTouchUpInside inside of a custom UIButton class in xcode

Tags: xcode, button, click

I am using a custom UIButton class and I was wondering if I could add code to the UIButton class in order to change the drawing of the button when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial to achieve what you are looking for.

[Programmatic uibutton with custom drawing](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/1/22/programmatic-uibutton-on-ios-70-create-a-uibutton-with-code)
Or you just need to create a IBAction for the UIControlEventTouchUpInside then programmaticaly change the frame, text and image of the button, save the currect state in a bool or int property.